# Mapping elements of nested list over values in a Python dict

Tags: python

Suppose there's a 3-level nested list, for example,

```
[[['<s>', '<s>', 'eu', 'rejects', 'german'], ['<s>', 'eu', 'rejects', 'german', 'call']],\
 [['eu', 'rejects', 'german', 'call', 'to'], ['rejects', 'german', 'call', 'to', 'boycott']]]
```

- level 1: sentence level
- level 2: context window level
- level 3: word/token level

**Task**: I'd like to map each token to its corresponding index with a pre-defined Python dictionary (e.g, `word2index['xx']=4`).

Output example:

```
[[[2522, 2522, 475, 1620, 397], [2522, 475, 1620, 397, 439]],\
 [[475, 1620, 397, 439, 4], [1620, 397, 439, 4, 1443]]]
```

The following is what I've done,

```
def word2index(input, model):
    """ Map words to index    
    """
    input2index = []
    for sent in input:
        sent2index = []
        for window in sent:
            window2index = []
            for elem in window:
                try:
                    index = model.vocab[elem].index
                    window2index.append(index)
                except KeyError:
                    unk = model.vocab['unk'].index
                    window2index.append(unk)
            sent2index.append(window2index)
        input2index.append(sent2index)
    return input2index
```

which involves lots of loops and creations of new list as intermediate containers. It'd be very easy to lose the track forgetting which container to append current data, especially when the nested list gets deeper.

**Question**: Would there be a more cleaner way to code such task?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`dict.get(key, default)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20get#dict.get) method to provide a default value instead of catching an Exception. This makes your computation a single expression, which is good for further inlining:

```
for elem in window:
    index = model.vocab.get(elem, unk).index
    window2index.append(index)
```

Which can be rewritten as:

```
window2index = [model.vocab.get(elem, unk).index for elem in window]
```

Which is faster in Cpython, and fairly straightforward.

Now, of course, you have a similar pattern for `sent`, and a similar pattern for `input`:

```
input2index = [EXPR-USING-sent for sent in input]

sent2index = [EXPR-USING-window for window in sent]

window2index = ... see above ...
```

So you can stack them all together as:

```
unk = model.vocab['unk']
input2index = [EXPR-USING-sent for sent in input]
return input2index
```

which becomes:

```
unk = model.vocab['unk']
input2index = [[EXPR-USING-window for window in sent] for sent in input]
return input2index
```

which becomes:

```
unk = model.vocab['unk']
input2index = [[[model.vocab.get(elem, unk).index
                for elem in window]
                for window in sent] 
                for sent in input]
return input2index
```

Comment: Great answer. However I pattern matched your last bit of code to flatten a 3d list to a 1d list, before tripping up when I saw the three `[[[` at the start of the comprehension. It may be something you want to look into, :)

Comment: Nice answer. One little nitpick on the final form. I would consider returning the nested list comprehension instead of  assigning it to a variable simply to return it.

Comment: Actually, I would too. But I know there's going to be some printing of data before it gets returned, just to check that it works :->

Comment: Can I set more than one default values by adding a if condition? For instance,  when `dict[k]` raises KeyError, assign a default value of `<s>` if `k<1`, else `</s>`.